# Display all current OS & 3rd party keyboard bindings

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

Is there any way to:

- display all native and 3rd party keyboard bindings in one place, similar to how Atom or [Visual Studio Code IDEs can](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings)?
- OR...allow me to type a keyboard shortcut and tell me the recipient app of the command (to find out what app gets triggered by a shortcut?)

My situation:

- I have a "rogue" app somewhere on my system that owns a keyboard shortcut I want to use for other purposes (CMD + Shift + 5)
- CMD + Shift + 5 on my Mac currently triggers some sort of screenshot app
- The mysterious screen-shot app works in a modal view, so I can't find the app name. It does not appear in the menubar
- I've looked in Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts and other places but no luck.

Comment: I think this one may use that shortcut.  https://www.getcloudapp.com/?utm_source=zapier.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=zapier

Comment: Thanks @TomGewecke - I found the app eventually (see answer below).

Answer (score 1):

I did not find a solution that could show the info I needed.

I ended up just deleting all the screenshot apps on my Mac until the keyboard conflict went away. Turns out it was an app called "Annotate", but that isn't really relevant.

Unfortunately I didn't find any solution for showing all currently mapped keyboard shortcuts on the Mac across ALL apps.